# Unexpected '(' in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Use the PhiPack software on our two aligned sets of sequences...
mkdir FcFeABC
cd FcFeABC
../bin/PhiPack/Phi -f ../../Data/Real_Sequences_and_Networks/FcFeABC_alignment.fas -o -v -w 10 -g
cd -

mkdir FcL10
cd FcL10
../bin/PhiPack/Phi -f ../../Data/Real_Sequences_and_Networks/FcL10_alignment.fas -o -v -w 10 -g
cd -

# Use the PhiPack software on the simulated Datasets...
cd ../Data/Simulated_Sequences_and_Networks/Constant_Sex/Theta\ =\ 0.066/Theta\ =\ 0.066/Medium/CutSequences/;
rmus=($(ls -d *.fas))
cd -
absfiles=(../Data/Simulated_Sequences_and_Networks/Constant_Sex/Theta\ =\ 0.066/Theta\ =\ 0.066/Medium/CutSequences/*.fas)
if [ ${#rmus[@]} = ${#absfiles[@]} ]
then
    mkdir ${rmus[@]}
    for ((i=0; i<${#absfiles[@]}; i++));
    do
        cd ${rmus[$i]}
    .../bin/PhiPack/Phi -f ${absfiles[$i]} -o -v -w 10 -g
        cd -
    done
else
    echo "Error, Number of files created and files to be read differs"
fi
```

Which hit's an error at line 16:

```
./runPhiTests.sh: 16: ./runPhiTests.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Which is this line:

```
rmus=($(ls -d *.fas))
```

I don't understand why the '(' is unexpected - it's a simple assignment of the results of ls to an array.

Thanks,
Ben W.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` should be `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't running it with `bash`. You are running with `/bin/sh` from your shebang line `#!/bin/sh`.

Either run with `bash` explicitly `bash runPhiTests.sh` or fix your shebang line `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use #!/bin/bash instead of sh.